# Javascript: Get all objects by specific field

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance

This might be a quite easy question, but I haven't encountered an elegant solution.

How do you get all objects from an array by a single field. For example;

```
var users = [{name:'John', age: 20}, 
{name:'Sarah', age: 21}, 
{name:'George', age:34}];
var names = magicFunction(users, 'name');
// names = ['John', 'Sarah', 'George']; 
// Another challenge is not to get field name (in this case 'name') with the value
```

I wonder if you could do it with functions like **filter** or **map**, without writing a long function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's pretty straight forward:

```
var prop = 'name';
var names = users.map(function(x) { return x[prop]; });
```

Or if you want to write this into a function:

```
function getProp(arr, prop)
{
    return arr.map(function(x) { return x[prop]; });
}

var names = getProp(users, 'name');
```

**Update** In ES6 syntax:

```
const getProp = (arr, prop) => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, x => x[prop]);
const names = getProp(users, 'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore.js (which you can install as a node package) has a function called `_.pluck` which does exactly this.  If you `_ = require("underscore")` you can actually replace `magicFunction` with `_.pluck`.

Answer (score 0):

@p.s.w.g is probably the solution you're looking for, but I'd like to show another one: using [core.operators](http://folktale.github.io/core.operators/).

```
var names = users.map(opts.get('name'));
```